# Syntax error in Bison after one token is processed

Tags: syntax-error, bison, token

I am trying to come up to speed on Flex and Bison.  I can parse one token with a very simple "language" but it fails on the second, even though the token is legitimate.

test.l:

```
%{
#include <stdio.h>
#include "test.hpp"
%}

%%
[0-9]+ {printf("Number entered\n"); return INTEGER_NUMBER;}
[a-zA-Z]+ {printf("plain text entered: '%s'\n",yytext); return PLAIN_TEXT;}
[ \t]   ;
.       ;
%%
```

test.y

```
%{
#include <stdio.h>

extern "C" {
  int yyparse(void);
  int yylex(void);
  int yywrap() { return 1; }
  extern int yylineno;
  extern char* yytext;
  extern int yylval;
}

/* #define YYSTYPE char * */

void yyerror(const char *message)
{
  fprintf(stderr, "%d: error: '%s' at '%s', yylval=%u\n", yylineno, message, yytext, yylval);
}

main()
{
  yyparse();
}

%}

%token PLAIN_TEXT INTEGER_NUMBER

%%
test : text | number;

text : PLAIN_TEXT
        {
          /*printf("plain text\n");*/
        };

number : INTEGER_NUMBER
        {
          /*printf("number\n");*/
        };

%%
```

Results:

```
$ ./test
cat
plain text entered: 'cat'

dog
plain text entered: 'dog'
1: error: 'syntax error' at 'dog', yylval=0

$ ./test
34
Number entered

34
Number entered
1: error: 'syntax error' at '34', yylval=0
```

Why am I getting this syntax error?

Answer (score 2):

Your `test.y` seems to lack the grammar for the case that several `test`s
continue.
So, how about adding the grammar like the following?

```
%%
tests : test | tests test; /* added */

test : text | number;

...
```

Comment: Oh, Ise, that is beautiful.  It is so obvious when you see it, but I don't think I was ever going to get there on my own.  I did have to make one little mod to get it to compile.  I had to put the right-hand side of the 'tests' line on it own line with a '|' at the beginning of the line.  (I tried to add that as code by prefacing each line with 4 spaces but it would not preserve the line breaks.)